# Java program. How do I loop my "isLucky method through the array? and how do I print the result in the main method?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

How do I print the result in the main method? And how do I loop the "isLucky" method to the array?  I posted a little bit ago and was told I should post again with less questions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunArrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    luckyNumber1 = 7;
    luckyNumber2 = 13;
    luckyNumber3 = 18;


    int[] a=new int[10];
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers...");
        for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        a[j] = sc.nextInt();

    boolean b = isLucky(a);

        int result; 

        if(b){
            result = sum(a);
        }

        else{
            result = sumOfEvens(a);
        }

}

public static int sum(int [ ] value)  
{
      int i, total = 0;
      for(i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
          total = total + value[ i ];
      }

      return (total);
}
static int sumOfEvens(int array[]) 
{
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
        sum += array[i];
}
return sum;
}
public static boolean isLucky (int[] array) 
{

    if ( array[i] == 7 || array[i] == 13 || array[i] == 18 )
        return true; 

    else
        return false;
}

// write the static methods isLucky, sum, and sumOfEvens
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public static boolean isLucky(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == 7 || array[i] == 13 || array[i] == 18)
            {
                System.out.println("Going to return true");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

printing the result by using `System.out.println("Result : "+result);` in your main method

Comment: wow thank you! very helpful! Does the System.out.println("Result : "+result); print the result for whichever is true?

Comment: Make two sout like System.out.println("Sum Result : "+result); and System.out.println("sumOfEvens Result : "+result); with in the condition check. It will print the result from which one.

Comment: So would I post System.out.println("Sum Result : "+result); below the actual result? Or would I just put both outside of that in the main method?

Comment: Like this,if (b)
        {
            result = sum(a);
            System.out.println("Sum Result : "+result);
        }

        else
        {
            result = sumOfEvens(a);
            System.out.println("sumOfEvens Result : "+result);
        }

Comment: My "isLucky" method.  it pops up a "else" without "if" statement

Comment: Like where did I compile or where did I put the system.out.println 's?

Comment: Already you did that code in you main method replace the code by what i gave you

Comment: I'm receiving multiple errors.  They are "cannot find symbol" errors.  The "LuckyNumber" numbers in the main method, and the "i" in the "isLuckyNumner" method.

Comment: replace main, public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[10];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers...");
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        {
            a[j] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        boolean b = isLucky(a);

        int result;
        if (b)
        {
            result = sum(a);
            System.out.println("Sum Result : "+result);
        }
        else
        {
            result = sumOfEvens(a);
            System.out.println("sumOfEvens Result : "+result);
        }
    }

Comment: replace sum and sumofEvens, public static int sum(int[] value)
    {
        int i, total = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            total = total + value[ i];
        }

        return (total);
    }

    static int sumOfEvens(int array[])
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum += array[i];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

Comment: replace isLucky method,  public static boolean isLucky(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == 7 || array[i] == 13 || array[i] == 18)
            {
                System.out.println("Going to return true");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: What about "i" in the "isLucky" method?

Comment: What i its used in the for loop so there is no problem